# Runtime creation and persistence of executable model rules

Tags: drools

We have the need to create and persist rules at runtime.  The goal is to create the rules, persist them and then reload them at a later point in time.  Using bits and pieces of code cobbled together from drools unit tests, I can successfully create rules from DRL strings and then persist them to a kjar.  And using the new KieBuilder.buildAll overload, the kjar (presumably) is built using the new executable model.  All of that seems to work.

But what I really want to do is eliminate the DRL strings entirely and create my rules at runtime using the flow or pattern DSL.  Again, using example code, I can create those rules at runtime, and execute them in a session.  What I can’t seem to do is actually persist them as a kjar (or any other form that I can devise).  It seems that the end result of building a rule using flow or pattern DSL is a KieBase.  And there seems to be no way to serialize or persist a KieBase.  At some point in the process, I need to be able to getBytes() in order to persist the KieBase.

For example, I can create the KieBase like this:

```
Rule rule = getRule();   
ModelImpl model = new ModelImpl().addRule( rule );  
KieBase kieBase = KieBaseBuilder.createKieBaseFromModel( model );
```

But I then need to be able to persist that newly created kieBase so it can be reloaded later.  And there doesn't seem to be a workable way to do that.

Any suggestions?  I’m using 7.7.0 for my testing.

**UPDATE 2018-07-23**

Let me clarify my original question with additional information.  There are really two use cases where I’d like to use the new executable model to author rules in Java:  1) at design time; 2) at run time.  Each use case has slightly different requirements, and so far I’ve been unsuccessful in getting either one to work completely.

For the 1st use case, at design time I need the ability to write rules in Java (using the new pattern DSL) and then save those rules to a kjar.  Once there, they can be loaded into a KieServer instance and executed.  Purportedly the Kie Maven Plugin can do this, and I’ve attempted to follow the instructions given in the drools doc (for example section 2.2.1.4 of the 7.8.0 doc).  But those instructions appear to be incomplete, and there just aren’t any examples of how to accomplish this.  What file or files need to be added to the resources\META-INF folder to identify the rules?  How are the rules actually exposed in the Java code?  Do they need to be in a particular type of class?  Are the rules returned from public methods?  How are those methods identified as having rules?  Are any Java annotations needed to make this work?

All of those questions would be answered for me if there was just one simple end-to-end example that demonstrated how to author a rule in Java, AND create the kjar containing that rule.

For the 2nd use case (actually the more important of the two for me), I need the ability to dynamically create rules at runtime.  Based on configuration data within our application, multiple rules need to be programmatically created and ultimately loaded into a KieServer instance.  My assumption was that the process would be similar to use case #1 where a kjar could be programmatically created and then loaded into the KieServer.  And remember that in this case, the Maven Plugin isn’t in the picture since this is all being done at runtime, not design time.  Using the examples for the executable model (primarily the unit tests), I can author the rules in Java, and I can execute them.  But I’ve found no way to actually build a kjar from them, or to directly load them into a KieServer.

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: I've followed the available examples/unit tests that create a Rule using the DSL. That Rule is added to a model and then the KieBase is created from that:  
Rule rule = getRule();   
ModelImpl model = new ModelImpl().addRule( rule );    
KieBase kieBase = KieBaseBuilder.createKieBaseFromModel( model );

Comment: try including your code in the question, please.

Comment: Creation of the KieBase is the easy part.  My question pertains to how do you then persist that KieBase?  Sorry about the formatting...I can't seem to get a hang of the Stackoverflow formatting :(I

Comment: Isn't the kjar a good serialization method for you?

Comment: The kjar would be perfect if I could actually construct one.  How exactly do you create the kjar from the KieBase containing the executable-model rules?  I've looked and just don't see a way to do that.  I'm assuming that I'm missing something.

Comment: @bruce --- Any more updates? I've seen [code that produces kjars](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.kie.api.builder.ReleaseId). Curious if you reached a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To execute the rules, they have to be in a specific Java file and the kjar needs to have a file into the META-INF folder stating where the rules actually are.

Take a look at what's the maven plugin doing here

https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/kie-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/kie/maven/plugin/GenerateModelMojo.java#L165

There will be probably an easier way in the future, but I can't tell you when.

Thank you for using the bleeding edge features, and good luck with that.